# PowerShell script runs from the shell, but not from my application

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a Windows Application that will be able to run a variety of Powershell scripts.

I have a script which works as it should (when run from the Powershell prompt), and my Windows Application seems to execute it like it should, but it is unable to find the methods on my OU.

When I execute the script from the Windows Application, I get these messages out:

> ERROR: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Create": "There
>    is no such object on the server.
>   "
>
> ERROR: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Delete": "There
>    is no such object on the server."

Powershell script:

```
function New-AdUser {

param (
    [string] $Username = $(throw "Parameter -Username [System.String] is required."),
    [string] $Password = $(throw "Parameter -Password [System.String] is required."),
    [string] $OrganizationalUnit = "Users",
    [string] $DisplayName,

    [string] $FirstName,

    [string] $LastName,

    [string] $Initials,
[string] $MobilePhone,
    [string] $Description,
    [switch] $CannotChangePassword,

    [switch] $PasswordNeverExpires,
    [switch] $Disabled

)

try {

    $currentDomain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()

    $dn = $currentDomain.GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName
    $ou = [ADSI] "LDAP://CN=$OrganizationalUnit,$dn"

    $userAccount = $ou.Create("user", "cn=$Username")

    $userAccount.SetInfo()



    $userAccount.userAccountControl = ($userAccount.userAccountControl.Item(0) -bxor 0x0002) #Enable the account

    $userAccount.SetInfo()


    $userAccount.sAMAccountName = $Username

    $userAccount.SetInfo()

    $userAccount.userPrincipalName = ("{0}@{1}" -f $Username, $currentDomain.Name)

    if ($DisplayName) {

        $userAccount.displayName = $DisplayName
    }

    if ($Description) {

        $userAccount.description = $Description
    }

    if ($FirstName) {

        $userAccount.givenName = $FirstName
    }


    if ($LastName) {
        $userAccount.SN = $LastName

    }


    if ($Initials) {

        $userAccount.initials = $Initials

    }



if ($MobilePhone) {
        $userAccount.mobile = $MobilePhone

}


    $userAccount.SetInfo()


    $userAccount.SetPassword($Password)

    # Password

    if ($PasswordNeverExpires) {

        $userAccount.userAccountControl = ($userAccount.userAccountControl.Item(0) -bxor 0x10000)
    }


    if ($CannotChangePassword) {
        $everyOne = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]'S-1-1-0'
        $EveryoneDeny = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ($Everyone,'ExtendedRight','Deny', [System.Guid]'ab721a53-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b')
        $self = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]'S-1-5-10'
        $SelfDeny = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ($self,'ExtendedRight','Deny', [System.Guid]'ab721a53-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b')

        $userAccount.get_ObjectSecurity().AddAccessRule($selfDeny)

       $userAccount.get_ObjectSecurity().AddAccessRule($EveryoneDeny)


       $userAccount.CommitChanges()
    }

    $userAccount.SetInfo()


    if ($Disabled) {
        $userAccount.userAccountControl = ($userAccount.userAccountControl.Item(0) -bxor 0x0002)

    }
    $userAccount.SetInfo()

} catch {

    Write-Error $_

    $ou.Delete("user", "cn=$Username")

    return $false

}

return $true
```

}

The C# code I have is this:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

            ps.AddScript(GetScript("New-AdUser.ps1"));
            ps.Invoke();

            ps.AddCommand("New-AdUser").AddParameters(
                new List<CommandParameter>() {
                    new CommandParameter("Username", username),
                    new CommandParameter("Password", password),
                    new CommandParameter("FirstName", firstName),
                    new CommandParameter("LastName", lastName),
                    new CommandParameter("DisplayName", realName),
                    new CommandParameter("Initials", initials),
                    new CommandParameter("MobilePhone", mobilePhone),
                    new CommandParameter("OrganizationalUnit", "Users"),
                    new CommandParameter("PasswordNeverExpires")
                }
            );

            var results = ps.Invoke();

            foreach (var obj in results)
                Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());

            if (ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var err in ps.Streams.Error)
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", err.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Calling a script "New-AdUser" is going to be confusing with the cmdlet of the same name in the AD module: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx

Comment: @richard only if he loads that module. He's not loading it here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint that the naming choice is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When run from within C# I found that I need to add the PowerShell snap-in "Microsoft.Windows.AD" before being able to run the cmdlet's it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are just creating a user in AD. By having the c# code calling a powershell script, you are adding another moving part in your script. Why not call it directly in C# code. Check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384369.aspx) article.

Comment: I have decided to go this way rather than the PowerShell solution.
At first I wanted to run the PowerShell files since the sys.tech.'s could maintain the files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the Create method on your ADSI object, `$ou`, doesn't exist.  I would check that it is getting created properly.  Run the script outside your application to ensure that it works, or have an extra line that displays its members:

```
$ou | Get-Member
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment - the exact same script works when I run it from the Powershell prompt.

Comment: So what does Get-Member return when run by the application?  I suspect the application is running as a different user or in a different context than when you run the script itself.

Comment: It simply outputs this

`static string ConvertDNWithBinaryToString(psobject deInstance, psobject dnWithBi
naryInstance)
static long ConvertLargeIntegerToInt64(psobject deInstance, psobject largeIntege
rInstance)`

The Windows application is executed from the same Windows user as when I test the script itself.

Comment: It seems that the parameters are not passed correctly.

If I add a line, "$Username", in the start of the powershell script I get different output when the Windows application executes the script.

When run from the prompt, I correctly get the string value that I passed.
When run from the Windows application, I get this: "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.CommandParameter"

Comment: Maybe PowerShell isn't loading the same profile when run through the app than on the command line?  And that is causing the difference?

Answer (score 0):

It almost appears as though the `Runspace` in the application is being created with a restrictive `RunspaceConfiguration`, so it can't find System.DirectoryServices for the AD functionality you need.

What do you get when you run the following within in your application?

```
string script = @"[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()";
PowerShell ps = new PowerShell();
ps.AddScript(script);
var output = ps.Invoke();
foreach (var a in output.Select(pso => (System.Reflection.Assembly)pso.BaseObject))
    Console.WriteLine("Assembly: " + a.FullName);
```

When I run that under the debugger in a plain console application I get 28 assemblies (19 outside the debugger), including `System.DirectoryServices`.  The `[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` bit shows 16 when I run it on a vanilla command prompt.  `System.DirectoryServices` shows up in all three lists.